# Determing sign of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is that true that for all positive integer $n$ and all $z \in (0,1)$:
$$
{( - 1)^n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{k^{2n}}{z^k}}  \ge 0
$$

Comment: @Tom, your link is broken

Answer (score 4):

The series is equal to
$$
(-1)^{n+1}\Bigl(z-2^{2n}z^2+3^{zn}z^3-4^{2n}z^4+\dots\Bigr)
$$
For sufficiently small $z$, the sequence $\{\,k^{2n}z^k\,\}$ is decreasing. It follows that
$$
z-2^{2n}z^2+3^{zn}z^3-4^{2n}z^4+\dots\ge z-2^{2n}z^2>0
$$
for sufficiently small $z>0$. Thus, the original sum is positive if $n$ is odd and negative if $n$ is even.

Comment: To elaborate a little bit on this excellent answer, $z-2^{2n}z^2=1^{2n}z^1-2^{2n}z^2>0$ because we've chosen $z$ so small that the sequence $\{k^{2n}z^k\}$ is decreasing, including $k=1$.  The series is greater than this inequality because it's an alternating series with decreasing terms.

Comment: Thanks for your solution !

Comment: What if we remove the term $(-1)^n$, for all $n>0$ and $z \in (0,1)$, is that $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{k^{2n}}{z^k}}  \ge 0 $$

Comment: Then it will be negative for small $z$.

Comment: I see. It's obvious. Thansk!